# week range of particular month year using mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to show date range of week by passing a variable which contains year and month i.e 2016-07 like this in mysql how could i achieve this:
for eg: if i pass 2016-07 then my output should look like this:

```
2016-07-03 to 2016-07-10 || 2016-07-11 to 2016-07-17
```

and so on

Comment: So you want the first date to be the first Sunday in 07 and the last date to be the last Sunday in 07?

Comment: no i want all week ranges in between also.let me clear for eg. if i want for May month then week ranges of that month & year would be like this:                        2016-05-01 to 2016-05-07    ||    2016-05-08 to 2016-05-14   || 2016-05-15 to 2016-05-21 || 2016-05-22 to 2016-05-28 ||2016-05-29 to 2016-06-04

Comment: What's the rule for deciding the first date is 2016-07-03 when you pass 2016-07? and what's the rule for the last date?

Comment: and how do you will know if a week starts in a month and ends in another one?
You must use javascript calendar to reach this. Otherwise, the easyest is to start entering data in some different tables and link it properly. then get data with appropiate select.

Comment: there is no any such rule i am just giving the example basically i have to show week date ranges of that particular month & year

Comment: actually i want to it in mysql only

Comment: CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month, INTERVAL (1 - DAYOFWEEK(month)) DAY), \'%Y-%m-%e\'), \' TO \', DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month, INTERVAL (7 - DAYOFWEEK(month)) DAY), \'%Y-%m-%e\')) AS DateRange  i have found something after doing lot of rearches but not working

Comment: If are allowed to do so the easiest way is to create a dates table for a large range of dates (10 years back + 10 years forward?) in excel and import it to mysql.

Answer (score 1):

There are several parts to solving this problem, when you go to solve it in MySQL.

One is to decide whether your weeks start on Sundays or Mondays. That's a locale-specific business rule. In locales formerly part of the British Empire (USA, India) it's usually Sunday. In other places, it's Monday.

So we'll need a function like this:   `firstDayOfWeek(date)`. More about that in a moment.

Once we have that, we'll need a way to get the last day of the month in question.  That's easy; it's a [built-in MySQL function. `LAST_DAY(date)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day)

You have said you'll specify the month in question with a string like `1941-12`. We'll need to turn that into a `DATE` object. That can be done like this:

```
  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`1941-12`, `-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

We need a virtual table with the integers from 0 to 4.  Let's call that table `seq_0_to_4`. We pick that range of integers because no months have more than five Sundays (or Mondays). More on that later.

OK, these are the conceptual building blocks. Let's use them.

The first day of the week derived from the last day of the month is

```
SET @month := '1941-12';
SET @first_day_of_month := STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`1941-12`, `-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
SET @seed : =FirstDayOfWeek(LAST_DAY(first_day_of_month));
```

Then you need four five consecutive week-starting days the last of which is @seed.

```
        SELECT @seed - INTERVAL (7*seq.seq) first_day_of_week
          FROM seq_0_to_4
```

Next you need to limit that to days in your month.

```
SELECT first_day_of_week, 
       first_day_of_week + INTERVAL 6 DAY last_day_of_week
  FROM (
        SELECT @seed - INTERVAL (7*seq.seq) first_day_of_week
          FROM seq_0_to_4
       ) w
 WHERE first_day_of_week >= @first_day_of_month
 ORDER BY first_day_of_week
```

That gives you a table of rows, one for each week beginning in the month. If you want to exclude weeks in which the last weekday is in the next month, change your WHERE to

```
 WHERE first_day_of_week >= @first_day_of_month
   AND first_day_of_week + INTERVAL 6 DAY <= @seed
```

Finally, to get the exact string format you specified in your question, wrap that query in this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT (
             CONCAT(first_day_of_week, ' to ', last_day_of_week) 
             SEPARATOR ' || '
             ORDER BY first_day_of_week)
  FROM (
        SELECT first_day_of_week, 
               first_day_of_week + INTERVAL 6 DAY last_day_of_week
          FROM (
                SELECT @seed - INTERVAL (7*seq.seq) first_day_of_week
                  FROM seq_0_to_4
               ) w
         WHERE first_day_of_week >= @first_day_of_month
       ) x
```

That's it.

I promised to describe `FirstDayOfWeek(dt)`. Here it is.

```
      FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(dt) -MOD(TO_DAYS(dt) -1, 7))
```

It's a bit of a magic spell, but it works. If your weeks start Mondays, it is this.

```
       FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(dt) -MOD(TO_DAYS(dt) -2, 7))
```

I promised to describe `seq_0_to_4`.  If you're using the MariaDB fork of MySQL, it's built in. If you're using the Sun / Oracle fork, you define it like this.

```
 (SELECT 0 AS seq UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) seq_0_to_4
```

Putting it all together:

```
SET @month := '1941-12';
SET @first_day_of_month := STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`1941-12`, `-01'), '%Y-%m-%d');
SET @seed := FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(LAST_DAY(first_day_of_month)) 
                       -MOD(TO_DAYS(LAST_DAY(first_day_of_month)) -1, 7));
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT (
             CONCAT(first_day_of_week, ' to ', last_day_of_week) 
             SEPARATOR ' || '
             ORDER BY first_day_of_week)
  FROM (
        SELECT first_day_of_week, 
               first_day_of_week + INTERVAL 6 DAY last_day_of_week
          FROM (
                SELECT @seed - INTERVAL (7*seq.seq) first_day_of_week
                  FROM      (SELECT 0 AS seq UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 
                                             UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
                            ) seq
               ) w
         WHERE first_day_of_week >= @first_day_of_month
       ) x
```

It's unreasonably complex (the technical term is *a freakin' hairball*) to solve your problem in pure MySQL-dialect SQL, but it's possible.

Comment: I'm presenting this so you can see the possibilities of SQL date arithmetic. I have not debugged it. My hope is that you'll learn from it and make it yours, not just copy it wholesale into your program.

Answer (score 0):

Probably is too late but i figured out this using Common Table expressions in MYSQL 8.0.2

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
Years(y) AS 
        (
        SELECT 2020
        UNION ALL
        SELECT y + 1 FROM Years WHERE y < 2021
        ),
Days (d) AS
        (
        SELECT 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT d + 1 FROM Days WHERE d < 366
        )
SELECT 
y AS Year,
MONTH(MakeDate(y,d)) AS Month,
WEEK(MakeDate(y,d))+1 -WEEK(TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH,MONTH(MakeDate(y,d))-1,MakeDate(y,1))) AS Week,
Min(MakeDate(y,d)) AS StartDate,
timestampadd(second,-1,timestampadd(day,1,MAx(MakeDate(y,d)))) AS EndDate
FROM Years,Days
WHERE Year(MakeDate(y,d)) <= y
GROUP BY y, MONTH(MakeDate(y,d)),WEEK(MakeDate(y,d))+1 -WEEK(TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH,MONTH(MakeDate(y,d))-1,MakeDate(y,1)))
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```